# How do you explain that in $y=x^2$, y is proportional to the square of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

My understanding is that all proportional relationships are linear relationships. If this is indeed the case, how is it that we can also say that in a non linear equation like $y = x^2$, y is proportional to $x^2$?

Comment: Here $y$ is not proportional to $x$ but to $x^{2}$; no contradiction.

Comment: ‘Proportional to $x^2$’ is not the same as ‘proportional to $x$’.

Comment: The definition of A proportional to B is that A = k B where k is a constant of proportionality. Here obviously k = 1 so y is proportional to x^2.

Comment: So is it not true that all proportional relationships must be linear? Because I have seen this stated in multiple locations.

Comment: @AlonzoArcher It means y is linearly related to x squared

Comment: A proportional to B means A is linearly related to B. In your example it means that y is linearly related to x squared.

Comment: Hi @Kartik, so this must be my problem. What does is mean to have a linear relationship in this scenario. I did not think equations with variables having a degree higher than 1 would be considered linear. Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @AlonzoArcher See my answer. I will include your second doubt also.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of proportionality is that $A \propto B \iff A = kB$. So A is linearly related to B, and also $A=0$ iff $B=0$.

In your case, $y = (1) x^2$ so y is actually proportional to $x^2$.

I think you are confused by "y is linear to x squared". Actually linear means that the power is 1. But when I say that y is linear to $x^2$ it means that if you take $x^2$ as one variable, lets call it $z$, then $y = z$ which is linear.

Linear also means that the graph is a straight line. If you draw a graph between y and x it is not a straight line. So  y is not linearly related to x. But if you make the x axis as $x^2$ it will become a straight line. Then we can say y is linearly related to to $x^2$.

Clarification for the graph:

Suppose we graph y = x^2. The result is a parabola.

[image]

But if you plot y on one axis and (x^2) on another axis, that means you dont plot y = x^2, but you treat x^2 as a single variable and you plot it along an axis, you then will get a straight line.

[image]

Here I have let x go from 1 to 5. On the horizontal axis, I have plotted the numbers $x^2$, i.e. $(1,4,9,16,25)$ and on the verticla axis, I have $y=x^2$, i.e. $(1,4,9,16,25)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Kartik. There is an area that confuses me in your discussion. Twice you said to graph y and $x^2$, but in one case you said it results in a parabola and in another a straight line. Can you offer some clarity?

Comment: @AlonzoArcher Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks for the graphs @Kartik! I think this is what I needed, and I believe that  I do understand now. Although the, one comment is that in the second sentence in your response, I think you meant to use an 'x' where you have a 'k'. Well, this is interesting, I don't think this perspective of proportionality was ever covered in my classes. I assume this is because it doesn't show up in many applications, but it sure seems to help you gain a deeper understanding of both what it means to be proportional and linear!

Answer (score 1):

$y$ is not proportional to $x$, beacause there is a quadratic relation between $x$ and $y$, but $y$ is proportional to $x^2$ as $y=\alpha x^2$ with $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Hi @Augustin, I get that point, but can you please speak of the linear nature of y and $x^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is called homothetic iff $f(ax) = af(x)$ for all $a,x \in \mathbb{R}$. In this sense, we say that $f(x)$ is  proportional to $x$. If $f: x \mapsto x^{2}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(ax) = a^{2}x^{2},$
which need not be $= af(x) = ax^{2}$, so $f(x)$ is not proportional to $x$.

Comment: Hi @Gudson Chou, I appreciate the formality of your response. I believe I understand the answer to my question now, but I am interested in being able to understand your formal response...just for the sake of understanding terms like "homothetic". It will take some research on my end, but I appreciate the response all the same.

Comment: The definition for a function to be homothetic has been given to you.

Comment: Hi @Gudson Chou, indeed the definition has been given to me...I suppose I meant I need to spend time getting to know the definition. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Gudson Chou, I started looking into "homothetic" functions and it looks like there are some other concepts like homogenous functions and affine space that one may get into in an attempt to understand homothetic. That is something that would take me some time. But, I actually can follow your reasoning without a deeper understanding of homothetic. I am curious as to whether the use of the homothetic definition for explaining proportionality is something that can be done for mathematical objects other than Real Numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $z = x^2$. Clearly in $y = z$, we can say "$y$ is proportional to $z$". (It's the same as $y = kz$ with $k = 1$). Then by back-substitution, we can say "$y$ is proportional to $x^2$".

Answer (score 0):

When we say "proportional to"  we often mean a linear variation.We are taught that way in the first place.  $y$ is proportional to $x^2 $ appears as a contradiction in its own terms, I for one agree with you.

A better way to say it is :

$ y $ varies as the  $ square $ of $x$.

In this general sense even if we say $y$ varies as the sine of square root of $x$.. no problem.

Comment: Hi @Narasimham, yeah it seems like it could be a reoccurring  source of confusion for students. In my opinion, care should be taken to make sure students are aware of what may on the surface seem like a contradiction. Even though I  now understand why it is not actually a contradiction, it seems as though something like the way you stated it is often the intended interpretion. Thanks for the post!